# How to query a single column using greenDAO 3?

Tags: greendao

I need to get data from a single column, but how can achieve this task using greenDAO?

The reason why I don't query all columns is that I think it will cut down efficiency, does it really matter?

Or greenDAO is too efficient so that it will not make any difference between query a single column or the whole entity?

Comment: could you get answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do `ItemDao.loadAll()`, you can perform `rawQuery(String query, String[] args)` on the database to get a column

```
List<ColumnType> column_content = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor mCursor = daoSession.getDatabase()
                .rawQuery("SELECT " + 
ItemDao.Properties.COLUMN1.columnName + " FROM " + ItemDao.TABLENAME, new String[0]);
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // The Cursor is now set to the right position
    column_content.add(mCursor.getColumnType(0));
}
```